# How to determine whether object is embossed or debossed using OpenCV?

Tags: python, c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

Let's say I have image with embossed and debossed object like this

[image: enter image here]

or

[image: enter image here]
Is there a way to determine the above object is embossed and the below object is debossed using OpenCV? Preferably using C++, but Python is also fine. I couldn't find any good resource on the internet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an approach which takes advantage of the sunken and lifted contours of the embossed/debossed image. The main idea is:

- Convert the image to grayscale
- Perform a morphological transformation
- Find outlines using Canny edge detection
- Dilate canny image to merge individual contours into a single contour
- Perform contour detection to find the ROI dimensions of top/bottom halves
- Obtain ROI of top/bottom canny image
- Count non-zero array elements for each half

Convert to grayscale and perform morphological transformation

[image]

Perform canny edge detection to find outlines. The key to determine if an object is embossed/debossed is to compare the canny edges. Here's the approach: We look at the object, if its upper half has more contour/lines/pixels than its lower half then it is debossed. Similarly, if the upper half has less pixels than its lower half then it is embossed.

[image]

Now that we have the canny edges, we dialte the image until all the contours connect so we obtain one single object.

[image]

We then perform contour detection to obtain the ROI of the objects

[image]

From here, we separate each object into top and bottom sections

[image]
[image]

Now that we have the ROI of the top and bottom sections, we crop the ROI in the canny image

[image]
[image]

With each half, we count non-zero array elements using [`cv2.countNonZero()`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#countnonzero). For the embossed object, we get this

```
('top', 1085)
('bottom', 1899)
```

For the debossed object, we get this

```
('top', 979)
('bottom', 468)
```

Therefore by comparing the values between the two halves, *if the top half has less pixels than the bottom, it is embossed. If it has more, it is debossed*.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

original_image = cv2.imread("1.jpg")
image = original_image.copy()
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5,5))
morph = cv2.morphologyEx(gray, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
canny = cv2.Canny(morph, 130, 255, 1)

# Dilate canny image so contours connect and form a single contour
dilate = cv2.dilate(canny, kernel, iterations=4)

cv2.imshow("morph", morph)
cv2.imshow("canny", canny)
cv2.imshow("dilate", dilate)

# Find contours in the image
cnts = cv2.findContours(dilate.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]

contours = []
# For each image separate it into top/bottom halfs
for c in cnts:
    # Obtain bounding rectangle for each contour
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)

    # Draw bounding box rectangle
    cv2.rectangle(original_image,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),3)
    # cv2.rectangle(original_image,(x,y),(x+w,y+h/2),(0,255,0),3) # top 
    # cv2.rectangle(original_image,(x,y+h/2),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),3) # bottom
    top_half = ((x,y), (x+w, y+h/2))
    bottom_half = ((x,y+h/2), (x+w, y+h))

    # Collect top/bottom ROIs
    contours.append((top_half, bottom_half))

for index, c in enumerate(contours):
    top_half, bottom_half = c

    top_x1,top_y1 = top_half[0]
    top_x2,top_y2 = top_half[1]
    bottom_x1,bottom_y1 = bottom_half[0]
    bottom_x2,bottom_y2 = bottom_half[1]

    # Grab ROI of top/bottom section from canny image
    top_image = canny[top_y1:top_y2, top_x1:top_x2]
    bottom_image = canny[bottom_y1:bottom_y2, bottom_x1:bottom_x2]

    cv2.imshow('top_image', top_image)
    cv2.imshow('bottom_image', bottom_image)

    # Count non-zero array elements
    top_pixels = cv2.countNonZero(top_image)
    bottom_pixels = cv2.countNonZero(bottom_image)

    print('top', top_pixels)
    print('bottom', bottom_pixels)

cv2.imshow("detected", original_image) 
print('contours detected: {}'.format(len(contours)))
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Very detail explanation! Thanks for remind me to use the `cv2.countNonZero()`

Answer (score 2):

One insight you could use is that an embossed object is usually brighter than a debossed object.

I would probably do an edge detection to find the "boss-edges" which should form a closed polygon, and compare the relative lightness value of the enclosed "bossment". Special care must be taken for objects with holes, e.g. the letter O, but it is do-able.

You can probably do more sophisticated processing if you know the light direction that is hitting the bossment.  e.g. if you know the light is coming from top left, you can try only focusing on the top left edge pixels

Comment: how do you compare the relative lightness value of the enclosed "bossment"?

Comment: You can convert it to [HSV colorspace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSV_color_space) and compare the V value